# C++ equivalent to C# Encoding.ASCII.GetString()

Tags: c#, c++, udp

I have a UDP socket in C# that sends a message using the following code

```cs
newsock.Send(sendBuffer, sendBuffer.Length, sender);
```

where `sendBuffer` is a `byte[]` data type.

How can I convert this message when I receive it in a UDP socket written in C++?

The C++ code is the following:

```cpp
recvfrom(socket_desc, client_message, sizeof(client_message), 0,(struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_struct_length)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the raw bytes in `client_message`, and `recvfrom()` will return the message's byte length. If the data is truly ASCII then just use the data as-is as a `char` string, there is no need to convert it.

But, if you need a C++ `std::string`, it has a constructor that takes a `char*` and length as input parameters.

On the other hand, if you really need a Unicode string (ie what `Encoding.GetString()` returns), you can use the Win32 `MultiByteToWideChar()` function, or equivalent, specifying ASCII as the charset to convert from.

Comment: I send a message like this:
```                bytes.Clear();
                lX = 1;
                lY = 1;
                lZ = 1;
                bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(lX));
                bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(lY));
                bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(lZ));
                

                sendBuffer = bytes.ToArray(); 
```
and I received a message like this:
```  
"\0\0\0\0\0\0ð?\0\0\0\0\0\0ð?\0\0\0\0\0\0ð?0\0\0\0"
```

Comment: That is not even text, let alone ASCII text, so why are you asking to convert that data using an `Encoding.GetString()` equivalent? Your data contains 3 binary 64bit integers, so just copy the `client_message` bytes as-is into an `int64_t[3]` array, eg: `int64_t nums[3]; memcpy(nums, client_message, sizeof(int64_t)*3); /* use nums[0]..nums[2] as needed... */` or just type-cast a pointer to `client_message` itself into an `int64_t*` pointer, eg: `int64_t *nums = (int64_t*)client_message; /* use nums[0]..nums[2] as needed... */`.